# Como Representar un DataTable En una Vista MVC Sin conocer las propiedades del DataTable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-3

Esto es lo que tengo en el controlador, creo una clase de prueba, la convierto a json y envio ese json a la clase que convierte cualquier json en un DataTable.

```
var Personas = new List<Personas>();
Personas.Add(new Personas() { Nombre= "Juan", Apellido="Lopez", Edad=30, FechaNacimiento = new DateTime(1987,01,25)});
Personas.Add(new Personas() { Nombre = "Elvin", Apellido = "Acevedo", Edad = 26, FechaNacimiento = new DateTime(1990, 06, 04) });
Personas.Add(new Personas() { Nombre = "Samuel", Apellido = "Acevedo", Edad = 26, FechaNacimiento = new DateTime(1991, 03, 26) });
Personas.Add(new Personas() { Nombre = "Carmen Rosa", Apellido = "Rodriguez", Edad = 23, FechaNacimiento = new DateTime(1987, 01, 25) });
Personas.Add(new Personas() { Nombre = "Pedro", Apellido = "Almanzar", Edad = 36, FechaNacimiento = new DateTime(1987, 08, 24) });
Personas.Add(new Personas() { Nombre = "Maria", Apellido = "Rodriguez", Edad = 19, FechaNacimiento = new DateTime(1998, 12, 25) });

var JsonPersonas = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Personas);
var dtpPersonas = Utilidades.ObtenerDataTabledeJson(JsonPersonas);

return View(dtpPersonas);
```

Esta es la Clase que convierte el Json TO DataTable

```
public static DataTable ObtenerDataTabledeJson(string Json)
{

        var jsonDeserializado = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Json);
        var jarray = jsonDeserializado as JArray;

        var TituloColumnas = jarray.Children().Children().Select(x => ((JProperty)x).Name).Distinct().ToList();

        var dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (var columna in TituloColumnas)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(columna);
        }

        foreach (var elemento in jarray)
        {
            var valores = elemento.Children().Select(x => ((JProperty)x).Value.ToObject<object>()).ToArray();
            dt.Rows.Add(valores);
        }
        return dt;
}
```

Y quisiera Representar ese DataTable en una vista MVC sin conocer las propiedades de dicho dateTable.

Vista.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h3>Datos De Personas</h3>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th></th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu vista puede poner algo como lo siguiente:

```
@model System.Data.DataTable
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (System.Data.DataColumn columna in Model.Columns)
            {
                <td>@columna.ColumnName</td>
            }
        </tr>        
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (System.Data.DataRow fila in Model.Rows)
        {
            <tr>                
                @foreach (System.Data.DataColumn columna in Model.Columns)
                {
                    <td>@fila[columna.ColumnName]</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Desconozco por qué estás usando *DataTable*, pero te estas perdiendo un **gran potencial de MVC**. Bien podrías pasarle directamente tu *lista de Personas* a la vista y usar los [templates de MVC](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-display-and-editor-templates/) en conjunto con [DataAnnotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx).

Espero que te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Te recomendaria que agregaras un ejemplo de codigo, para que sea mas facil interpretar la respuesta, ya que los enlaces externos tienden a fallar.